# Selecting vertices in certain vertex group or certain weight

Tags: vertex-groups, geometry-nodes, instances, vertex-weights

I am using blender 3.0.0 Beta
I have a plane with many vertices and want to raise one of the vertices higher than others using geometry nodes.
[image]
I have two approaches : 1- vertex groups  2- weighted vertices 
Whatever you can help is welcome. I have tried to select and separate both ways and all of my efforts have failed so far.
[image]
Please help to understand how the selection works in Blender 3 geometry nodes.
Also the raised vertex at the moment is a manual raise 
So the ideal output would be :
[image]

Comment: What is the reason for downvotes ? I have a vertex in a plane that I want to raise it using geometry nodes. Isn't here the right place to ask this question? please explain your downvotes.

Comment: Hey Spongebob - don't be angry. Just take it as it is. It is a waste of time to even think about it. If you are longer here you might even make worse experiences. But...there are also a lot of really kind, helpful people here...and some are kind of genius...you will see. And that's worth it!!

Comment: what i can think of is...your question is about Blender3.0beta. And some here take the "rules" which are in here VERY strict - they seem to think the are the sheriffs here - but they don't treat people equally - they just do this on special people...mostly just on the "new ones". So the "official" rule is, that this here is just for officially released software...BUT of course you will find a lot of "still" open and answered questions about Blender 3.0

Comment: And to make you feel  a bit better - i upvoted your question ;)

Comment: @Chris I didn't know that only questions from stable versions of blender are answered here. I always use development version :(

Comment: @Harisreedhar: Nobody who asks here for the first time "reads the rules" and...to be honest...it is a waste of time. But yeah...that are the rules....if you want to have a link...i can send it to you.... ;) And i do it as you do - i always use the latest development version...so the most unstable one - which in my experience - is really stable - and i know what i am talking about - i was software developer for centuries... ;)

Comment: @Chris Yes please give rules link

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6 ...and if you click the links you can read for days...and somewhere you can read about beta versions. Although always the same people here will  reprove you if you ask about Blender development versions here....

Comment: Thanks. IMO atleast beta version should be considered.

Comment: IMO all Blender versions…☺️

Comment: But just search for geometry nodes. The last questions were all about the newest versions…that’s what make me angry. The moderators don’t treat the people equally. Some which they don’t like, they close the questions and other are allowed to do exactly the same. Because they are afraid of offending „old“ people with big reputations like Gandalf ( I just took someone…I don’t say he didn’t hold the rule)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Index` and `Compare Floats` node for selecting particular point.

In this example 70th index is selected.
[image]

To select only a vertex group you can use this node setup:

[image]

Press this button [image] in the modifier to toggle it to attribute.

Comment: Thanks Harisreedhar
Is there any way to check VertexGroup name or Weight value of a vertex ?

Comment: Did you mean importing vertex weight into GN and use it as selection?

Comment: In that case create float field in `Group input` node and from the GN modifier tab you can put vertex group into that foat field.

Comment: i added it to you answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you @Chris

Comment: Thanks Harisreedhar and @Chris
Now I know how the selection works! I was thinking inside the box!!! 

Comment: Thanks for this! The Blender documentation hasn't been updated as of this date at least so I don't know how else I could have learned this.