# Driving point scatter density with a Vertex Group using Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm struggling with Geometry Node point scattering since most available tutorials are using the old nodes. I can't even figure out how to call up a specific attribute -- none of the new nodes seem to have the attribute field built-in like the old ones. Am I missing something simple here?
Anyway, here's what I've done so far. The geo already has a vertex group, so how do I use it to drive the density in the 'Distribute Points on Faces' node?

Using Blender 3.0.0

[image]

Comment: Similar question on importing vertex group: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244147/selecting-vertices-in-certain-vertex-group-or-certain-weight?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks! I had actually already looked at that post, but because you linked it here I went back and had a second look. This time, I caught the additional info tacked on at the end and was able to figure this out!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here's a clear answer with a screenshot. Connect the unused output on the 'Group Input' node to the 'Selection' input on 'Distribute Points on Faces'. A new field will now appear in the geometry node modifier panel. Click the little Attribute Toggle button and then type in the name of your vertex Group.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for figuring this out. The 3.0 documentation (as of this date) is simply WRONG and shows an old way to do it with node options that don't exist any more. Your technique is the first I found that works with up to date release of blender.